# Why Intellij deletes obsolete files when trying to run DevMode?

Tags: java, gwt, intellij-idea

I'm currently working on a GWT project in my company. Although DevMode works perfectly fine in eclipse, I still want to use Intellij Ultimate Edition for development.

But after all setups were done (Facet, Run/Debug configuration) I'm getting this weird processing window saying "Deleting Obsolete Files..." when I run the program and after that all my pre-deployed resource files in the war directory were gone (recursively...).

BTW, I use a script to deploy all my stuff. And the only argument I set for DevMode is:

**-war /absolute/path/before/war/folder/war**

Does anyone know the reason why Intellij is deleting my files?

Comment: Is it the case that you can't just... *rebuild* your WARs?

Comment: the build process is totally decoupled from running previously, so the only thing i wanted to do is simply run the project with proper configuration, but the IDE seems getting in the way of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After sending a request to Intellij support team, they gave me the following answer:

Adding the following two lines to the IDEA_HOME/bin/idea.properties file:

**idea.gwt.clear.unit.cache.before.run=false**

**idea.gwt.clean.files.created.by.dev.mode=false**

Which makes sense, because the only thing I need is to prevent Intellij from deleting my local cached files. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I switched to IntelliJ from Eclipse and never had a problem with GWT debugging in IntelliJ. It is most likely deployment-related.

First, I use Tomcat on the client side just like I'd use it in production. No built-in Jetty. Specify -noserver in Dev Mode Parameters. And make sure to start you server (in Debug mode since you are likely to debug it as well).

Other than that you may be doing custom build/deployment which is causing it. I do everything by the book. IntelliJ is Maven-centric, so it needs to be a textbook Web App module. Unlike Eclipse you don't need to specify where you war directory is. It is "webapp" per Maven convention. I suggest recreating the module from scratch.

Comment: Actually i am using custom building and package management system. But for deployment I think is just configured by Intellij. 

Although I'm not quite sure about the deployment behavior in Intellij right now. Since it is not mentioned anywhere that Intellij will clean my war directory nor how Intellij interacts with custom build/package management system.

Comment: You cannot trust the IDE to build and deploy. Otherwise you'd as well run it from the IDE in Prod. I've seen people running production systems in the good old JBuilder on some notebook. Change your project structure to standard (Maven) and you'll never have problems like this again.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I would try to do the migration if it's not a big and pretty completed company project. Currently it would be a pain if I modify the project structure.